# Router on MAC Whitelisted Network

Tags: networking, mac, router

I'm trying to connect a router (RT-AC68U Advanced Tomato) to an existing network with MAC Address whitelisting. The router is on the whitelist and can access the internet itself (SSH in, can ping and wget) but devices connected to the router cannot. I know this is possible to achieve on this network as the Windows Ad Hoc "Mobile Hotspot" allows other devices to connect and share the connection. That method also ignore's the MAC Whitelist and allows mDNS sharing. I'm doing this as the parent network has isolation for every device and I require network discovery and mDNS for a project.

I'd like the Router to act as a switch and AP but most importantly I'd like sharing between devices. So, how can I enable LAN devices access to the WAN?

Comment: (1) Enable NAT on the router, and all outgoing traffic should have the MAC of the router, and therefore be on the whitelist. (2) Configure your router to bridge LAN and WAN, then both LAN and WAN devices are in the same segment.

Comment: Thanks @dirkt, that almost works. This makes the router behave "transparent". When the WAN cable is connected to the router, my PC receives an IP via DHCP from the parent router in the range of "10.119.xxx.xx" instead of "192.168.11.xx" and I cannot access the settings page of my router as it is not the default gateway. To access my router I have to disconnect WAN and reboot, I can then access via "192.168.11.1". Also, in a traceroute my router never appears "tracert google.com" jumps directly to the parent router.

Comment: Sorry, I meant WLAN, not WAN, and can't edit it anymore. Bridging LAN and WAN *doesn't* work with whitelisting, so either there's no whitelisting (your router MAC), or something else is happening. In any case, that was not what I was talking about, but as long as it works ...

Answer (score 0):

If you enable NAT and bridge LAN and WLAN, you should get something like this:

```
       <-------- RT-AC68U  ------->

                    192.168.11.1
                        MAC2
                 ------bridge------
       WAN       LAN         WAN AP
       MAC1      MAC3          MAC4
      10.119.*    :            :
        |         :            :
   <----+        192.168.*  192.168.*            
   to existing   MAC5       MAC6
   router        Client1    Client2
```

Client1, Client2 and the internal port 192.168.11.1 of the bridge (to access the router) are all in the 192.168.11.0/24 segment, and all of these should be able to talk to each other. When they want to access the existing network, the RT-AC68U does not, and changes each outgoing packet into a packet from 10.119.* (the address it got on the WAN port) with MAC1.

With the configuration you got by following my typo (WAN instead of WLAN), the RT-AC68U acts as a switch, and if there is really whitelisting, only one client will be able to talk to the existing network.

Comment: I've since changed to DD-WRT but still can't get it to work. The WAN and LAN&WLAN still seem to be separate. Devices can see eachother and even the router in the network, but cannot access the intenet. The router still can if you SSH in. The Router is in Operating Mode Router with Dynamic Routing LAN & WLAN. Also tried Gateway mode but to no avail.

Comment: So the NAT is not working. How did you configure it?

Comment: I belive all I may have done is enable uPnP as I couldn't find many other NAT options. Do you suggest I do something with iptables? I did try something with iptables but coudln't figure it out in the brief time I attempted, I've been away since then and I'll now search to see if  I can discover something else.

Comment: Yes, NAT is implemented using iptables, but the GUI should take care of that. I'm not familiar with Advanced Tomato, and couldn't find a manual for it. If I read the Tomato [Menu Reference](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Tomato_Firmware/Menu_Reference#Basic) correctly, NAT seems to be enabled by default. Look at the current `iptables` rules (`iptables -t xxx -S` for xxx = `raw`, `mangle`, `nat`, `filter`). There are plenty of online tutorials that explain NAT.

Comment: I've changed to using DD-WRT instead of Advanced Tomato now. Even after experimenting with iptables manually via SSH I couldn't get it to work. I tried clearing all existing tables and trying rules like 'iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o 'get_wanface' -j MASQUERADE' or 'iptables -t mangle -I POSTROUTING -o 'get_wanface' -j TTL --ttlset 128' but to no avail.

Comment: Both DD-WRT and Advanced Tomato really should have NAT right of the box, because that's a default mode of operation with the routers. If you've never done NAT before yourself, randomly adding iptables rules is not going to help. Please edit question with output of `iptables -t xxx -S` as described above so I can verify NAT is active. The way to debug networking stuff is to `tcpdump` on relevant interfaces, do a `ping` on the route you want to test and see if it behaves as it should.

Comment: My box reports that '-S' is an invalid argument and so I used -L instead. I've posted the results [Here](https://pastebin.com/raw/SSKMCUcT)

Comment: Ok, this looks complicated, and I don't fully understand what they are doing - they are only doing DNAT, but they are marking some packets, so probably they use policy routing. From my side, this would need a quite a bit of free time to work through, even with the rest of the missing configuration information, so I suppose so you should ask someone more familiar with DD-WRT or Advanced Tomate how this is set up and what goes wrong in your setting.

Comment: Alright, thank you for your help. It's been interesting learning this all so far.